# How to have onFormSubmit(e) and onEdit(e) together nested

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, javascript-scope

I want onFormSubmit(e) to be my main function trigger and within that I want onEdit(e) to be nested. Basically, no matter, the trigger will run onFormSubmit but it will do others within the onEdit if there is any edit, if there isn't then it will do something else.

I can't see to understand and make it work.

My script triggers shows onFormSubmit as the only function and onEdit is not in the dropdown.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit").timeBased().after(60000).create();
  function onEdit(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('SpeedVSD');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses 1");
    var row = ss.range.getRow();
    var col = ss.range.getColumn();

    if (col >= ss.getColumn() && col <= ss.getLastColumn() && row >= ss.getRow() && row <= ss.getLastRow()){
      console.log("You edited a Cell within Range");

    }

  }
```

edit: Managed to get my lastRow value. However, I am still looking to get a command that can get the lastRow value for all the columns instead of manually doing it.

edit: Using a `FOR` Loop helps with collating the values.

````
//This is to get the Last Row on Column 2 value.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName('FIRST');

  var row = sheets.getLastRow();
  for(var i = 1; i <= sheets.getLastColumn(); i++){
  var myID = sheets.getRange(row, i).getValue();
  }

  console.log("Row Number: "+row);
  console.log("Content of last Row: "+myID);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName('FIRST');
  var row = sheets.getLastRow();
  var myIDCol2 = 2;
  var myIDCol3 = 3;
  var myID2 = sheets.getRange(row, myIDCol2).getValue();
  var myID3 = sheets.getRange(row, myIDCol3).getValue();
  console.log("Speed Before Trigger Value: "+myID2);
  console.log("Voltage Before Trigger Value: "+myID3);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("responsechange").timeBased().after(60000).create();

  }

function responsechange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName('FIRST');

  var row = sheets.getLastRow();
  var myIDCol2 = 2;
  var myIDCol3 = 3;
  /*for(var i = 1; i <= sheets.getLastColumn(); i++){

    console.log("Content of last Row: "+myID);
  }*/
   var myID2 = sheets.getRange(row, myIDCol2).getValue();
  var myID3 = sheets.getRange(row, myIDCol3).getValue();
  var template1 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("speed1");
  var template2 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("voltage");
  template1.speed1 = myID2;
  template2.voltage = myID3;
  console.log("Speed After Trigger Value: "+myID2);
  console.log("Voltage After Trigger Value: "+myID3);







  if((myID2 >=100) || (myID2 <= 50)){
    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com","Out of Range Notification Speed","",{htmlBody: template1.evaluate().getContent()});
  }

  if((myID3 >=100) || (myID3 <= 50)){
    MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com","Out of Range Notification Voltage","",{htmlBody: template2.evaluate().getContent()});
  }

  }
```

With this, I managed make it work whereby on form submit, lets say the values are below 50 and above 100, it will trigger an email after the time-based trigger. I also tried within the time-based trigger, I edited the values to be within the range and it did not send an email. However, the only problems now is, if there are many triggers, it will stop the trigger by saying 
**This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.**

But on the bright side, I managed to get the last value submitted to have it checked if it was edited or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `onEdit()` to run always, you just create it as a separate function. then you can call it from the `onFormSubmit()`, like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
   //does something you need...
   onEdit();
}
onEdit(e){
   //do the onEdit code...
}
```

The only problem with this is that the event `e` for `onFormSubmit()` is different than the one for `onEdit()`, so working with events might not be the best idea. However, calling one function from the other would fun just like with any other function.

Comment: This ``onEdit`` is just a normal function right? It doesn't invoke the properties of a ``function onEdit(e)`` right?

Comment: I'm getting undefined for my ``ss.range.getRow();`` and ss.range.getColumn();``

I have tried to replace the ``e`` to ``ss`` but it still did not work. Am I doing it right or is there something I am missing

Comment: This `onEdit()` would indeed act with the trigger, meaning it will get called in the case of an edit to the sheet, whether it uses `e` as a parameter depends on what you need. As for the undefined, what are you trying to get from `ss.range.getRow();` and `ss.range.getColumn();`?

Comment: To get the active row and columns or am I using the wrong statement for it?

Comment: What do you mean active, the one that got edited? or one that's selected in the Sheet currently?

Comment: I got it fixed @AMolina. Now, the issue is, I want to have a ``onFormSubmit`` event and also an ``onEdit``. I have to send an email if the values is out of range, but I put a trigger timing for 1minute. If within 1 minute, there is a change of values and the the values are within the range, then it wont send an email. But if it does not get edited(meaning its not a typo), then it will send an email after 1 minute.

Comment: If you're checking for the users writing into the "out of bounds area" then the `onEdit()` would be your best bet, you can read the cell that was edited and send the email accordingly. I think you should ask a new question, editing existing ones into new questions is not a good practice in SO, makes everything confusing for people with similar issues.

Comment: Got it. I got it to work. You can check the answer below. Thanks for helping out!